# Spring boot custom 404 page fails when try to access static subfolder

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot project (1.5.2) with a custom 404 page stored in /public/error/404.html

In my project I have also some static content

```
    /static
      |- folder1
      |- folder2
```

The error page is correctly called when I try to access a wrong path (like "folder1/asd").

But if a try to access an existing subfolder (not file within the folder, but the folder itself like "/folder1"), Spring boot doesn't return a 404 error (and the relative page), but return a 200 with a octect/binary content response of length 0.

How I can redirect also this paths to the error page?

I can't do an explicit map for every subfolder becouse they are many.

I'm using the enbedded Tomcat.

Comment: Which Spring boot version are you using? Do you have any other configuration that could be relevant? I can't reproduce this in a new project  with Spring boot  2.1.2.

Comment: @g00glen00b Spring Boot 1.5.2, then I have some comfiguration for the security part, but I get the error after the authentication process.

Comment: I've just tried with an empty Spring boot 1.5.2 project and some folders with some files in, and I'm properly seeing the  contents of `404.html` when I go to `http://localhost:8080/folder1/`. Make sure you post all relevant code to reproduce the problem.